# Get one item of each array and check a condition with both

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have the following using Typescript:

```
private baskets$: BehaviorSubjectBasket[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Basket[]>([]);

private products$: BehaviorSubject<Product[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]);
```

Given `BasketId` and `ProductId` I need to get a `Basket` and a `Product` and check a condition with both:

```
result: Observable<boolean> = this.baskets$.asObservable().pipe(
    map(baskets => baskets.find(x => x.basketId === basketId)),
    map(basket => Check condition with basket and product);
```

My problem is how to get the product and use it in the condition along with the basket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a combine operator like so:

```
result: Observable<boolean> = combineLatest(this.baskets$.asObservable(),
                                            this.products$.asObservable(),
                                            ).pipe(
                                 map(([baskets, products]) => /*... do what you need here */),
                               );
```

I like `combineLatest` but there is also `forkJoin`, `zip`, etc. with slight variations.